# Why was my question downvoted and closed?

Tags: discussion

In regards to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/173136/80950). Why? As a long term participant of many stackexchangr sites, I simply can not come up with any explanation except targeted downvoting.

Comment: I don't think the question should have been closed, but I agree with all of the down-votes. To argue with Le Chatelier's principle and not bother to find out the correct spelling is usually an indicator that a question was not researched well enough to be asked here. You are making the same mistake with this meta question. If you don't care, why should we?

Comment: If you're going to write inflammatory comment of this type then you will kill the cohesion of this comment, if any exists already. Firstly its bad faith, and if you had read the accepted answrr , youd have seen its a common misconception. Typically when a person utters, something that is wrong, they may not even know where exactly they are wrong @Martin-マーチン

Comment: Now, that additional downvote in the morning just felt like bullying. Come on, really?

Comment: What do you mean by targeted downvoting? Do you understand how votes work? Please visit the help pages otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was my post closed and how to improve it](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/why-was-my-post-closed-and-how-to-improve-it)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why the post was voted down and put on hold but I have some ideas.

Real world scenarios are typically controlled by many variables, in your case: the heating system in the residence, the geometry of the residence, air flow and heat exchange within the residence and with the surroundings, air quality (T, humidity, heat capacity) in all of the coupled volumes, etc. Such types of questions (similar to chemical engineering problems) might require more details.

A bigger problem with the formulation is that it sought an explanation specifically in terms of Le Chatelier's principle. While sharing your thoughts is encouraged, this might have led to confusion. I re-read the final sentence

> Does L'chateliers principle really hold when there is no heat energy to evaporate the water?

many times and am still having trouble understanding what you mean. Invoking Le Chatelier's principle is probably unnecessary and confusing.